# Dataframe, creating a new column with values based on another column's indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, slice

I want to create a new column and give it values from a second column based on index numbers.

The dataframe is `df4`. The existing column is `SalePrice` and the new column I want to create is `Label`.

I want `Label` to have 3 different values depending on the index number of `SalePrice`, since `SalePrice` is sorted based on its values.

Here's how I went about it:

```
df4.loc[df4.SalePrice.index<int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)/3),"Label"]="Expensive"
df4.loc[df4.SalePrice.index>int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)/3),"Label"]="medium" 
df4.loc[df4.SalePrice.index>int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)*2/3),"Label"]="Low"
```

so this works but I think there might be a more efficient and better way of doing this...I tried using a range in the second command line

```
df4.loc[df4.SalePrice.index>int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)/3)& df4.SalePrice.index<int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)*2/3),"Label"]="Medium"
```

but then I get:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'RangeIndex'"
```

I would be grateful for an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You just have to place some parentheses:

```
df4.loc[(df4.SalePrice.index>int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)/3)) & (df4.SalePrice.index<int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)*2/3)),"Label"]="Medium"
```

Every statement must be in parentheses `(...) & (...)`, otherwise pandas can't parse the filter.

You may also refactor your code by extracting the filters:

```py
    mask_expensive = df4.SalePrice.index < int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)/3)
    mask_low = df4.SalePrice.index > int(len(df4.SalePrice.index)*2/3)
    mask_medium = (~ mask_expensive) & (~ mask_low)
    df4.loc[mask_expensive,"Label"]="Expensive"
    df4.loc[mask_medium ,"Label"]="medium" 
    df4.loc[mask_low,"Label"]="Low"
```

By doing that, your code is easier to read. Also, this fixes a little bug in your code, because the `==` case was not defined before.